# Finding the equation of oblique asymptote of non-rational function

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the function: $f(x)=2x-2^{x}+2$

I know that this function has an oblique asymptote, but all the tutorials I can find on google, are with rational functions with the form:

$$f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

Where they simply just divide the denominator with the numerator.

But I can't do that, because my equation doesn't contain any fractions. So my question is: how do I find the function to the oblique asymptote for my $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An asymptote is a line that approximates the function as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.
In other words, you want a function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{2x-2^x+2}{ax+b}=1
\end{equation}
This is not possible for $x\rightarrow +\infty$ since the $2^x$ explodes, so you could have an asymptote only for $x\rightarrow -\infty$:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{2x-2^x+2}{ax+b}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(\frac{2x+2}{ax+b}-\frac{2^x}{ax+b}\right)=1
\end{equation}
Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{2^x}{ax+b}=0$, you are left with
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{2x+2}{ax+b}=1
\end{equation}
which yelds $a=2$, $b=2$

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: :) Actually Mosk' answer below is a bit more formal and general!

Answer (score 4):

$$\text {Hint: for}\ {x\to -\infty}, \ {2^x\to0}$$
$$\text{the oblique asymptote has the form }\ y=mx+q$$
$$\text{and to find m and q you calculate the following limits:}$$
$$\ m=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\ f(x)/x$$
$$\ q=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\ [f(x)-mx]$$